# Showing NERDTree bookmark relative to project/directory

Tags: vim, nerdtree

[NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) keeps list of all bookmark in `$HOME/.NERDTreeBookmarks` file .When I hit <kbd>B</kbd> it show all entries from that file.So I tried having a local copy of this file with project specific bookmark but this does not work :(

Is there a way to see only project related bookmark in NERDTree ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I use for git repo specific NERDTree bookmarks.

```
    if isdirectory(expand(".git"))
      let g:NERDTreeBookmarksFile = '.git/.nerdtree-bookmarks'
    endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no way to tell how a project directory is structured, it seems like the use of a shell environment variable is the easiest solution.

First, add path to your bookmarks:

```
export NERDTREE_BOOKMARKS="/full/path/.NERDTreeBookmarks"
```

Then add this to your `~/.vimrc` or similar:

```
if !empty($NERDTREE_BOOKMARKS)
    if filereadable($NERDTREE_BOOKMARKS)
        let g:NERDTreeBookmarksFile = $NERDTREE_BOOKMARKS
    endif
endif
```

Depending on how you develop, the use of environment variables may or may not be a suitable solution. I.e. if you open/close your shell all the time, or have a multitude of shells open at once.

A simpler alternative could be something like this, but it'll only work if you open vim/a file with vim in the directory the bookmarks are located.

```
if filereadable(".NERDTreeBookmarks")
    let g:NERDTreeBookmarksFile = ".NERDTreeBookmarks"
endif
```

Comment: Its works only if i open gvim from directory where .NERDTreeBookmarks file is stored.

Comment: @deven98602 I just updated my answer because of just that flaw. However it's still a somewhat problematic use case depending on how your workflow is. An alternative could maybe be to temporarily set `g:NERDTreeBookmarksFile` in `~/.vimrc` when working on your project.

Answer (score 2):

As timss already pointed out, the key setting is the `g:NERDTreeBookmarksFile` config variable. You need to find a way to manipulate that (global) setting depending on the project that is currently open. Using external environment variables is one solution; I would rather solve this with one of the *local vimrc* plugins that are available on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/); I use [localrc.vim - Enable configuration file of each directory](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) myself.

In each different project dir, you create a `.local.vimrc` script that sets the above variable to the project's bookmark file. (This only works reliably when you only ever open one project at a time in Vim.)

Comment: I am putting folln code `if filereadable(".NERDTreeBookmarks")
    let g:NERDTreeBookmarksFile = ".NERDTreeBookmarks"
endif` in my .local.vimrc. The path in g:NERDTreeBookmarks points to my project specific bookmark file but the list comes from $HOME/.NERDTreeBookmarks . IT seems like .local.vimrc gets loaded late

Comment: Its not possible to execute that from .local.vimrc?

Comment: It is only available inside the NERDTree buffer. You'd have to go there first, or invoke the function it's calling yourself.

Comment: @IngoKarkat If a custom `NERDTreeBookmarksFile` is defined in a `.vimrc` and loaded, there shouldn't be any need to explicitly update them with `:ReadBookmarks` in the NERDTree buffer. Atleast it's not with my example.

Comment: @timss Right, as long as you launch a new Vim solely for your project, a conditional in `.vimrc` or your approach would work. If you re-use a single Vim instance or edit multiple projects in parallel, you need something like a local .vimrc.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Aye, I like the idea of using something like `localrc.vim` in this case, but either way I don't believe you should have to explicitly read your bookmarks. If the configuration has been loaded in your vim session, either by plugin or "dumb" conditional in `~/.vimrc` it should be used by NERDTree.